# How to maintain form values of previous form while clicking back button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-forms

I want to maintain the form values of the previous form when we are clicking the back button on the next one.

So actually, I'm storing all the form values in a state called InstructionData the only issue I have is in the function which was called when we click the back button.
I don't want to use history because I don't want to navigate it to another route that's why I'm calling an action to set the screen when back button is called.

Now, the question arises that how to put all this thing into a function
So onBackButtonClick is the function which would be called on clicking the back button, InstructionData stores the data. and I need to put this instructionData in the initial form values

onBackButtonClick = (InstructionData) => {

?????

}

I need help with the function. Thanks

Comment: If you [lift up the form state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a component that doesn't unmount during navigation, you can simply pass it down to the form and it will retain all values no matter to which step you move.

Comment: yes, but I need to retain those values when I click the back button, so would that be implemented in the backbutton function? @ChrisG

Comment: No, your question means you didn't understand my suggestion. Lifting up state is a basic react mechanism and means you move up a state variable to a parent, then pass down the value and a setter function to the child. If you do this, you don't have to worry about the back button at all; you just make it display the previous part of the form, and since the form values are passed down as props from the parent, all previously entered data reappears.

Comment: Here's the basic idea: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-meadow-ebgov?file=/src/App.js (I've never used formik though, so you might have to adjust this accordingly)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, your form is in Page A and after submitting the form, you are navigating to page B. Use `window.history.pushState(InstructionData, "URLofPageA")` in page A inside your submit form function. This pushes your form value to the history stack. Now you can retrieve the form data by calling `window.history.state` in page A (mostly in `useEffect()`). And you can use `setValue()` of `useForm()` hook to set the values to specific input field.

More on history state: [Working with the History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API), 
Read `pushState` documentation: [History.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

This is my first answer here, so please pardon my mistakes. :)